# migrating minor rails versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I started a new rails project a few weeks ago with 3.2.3. Today I noticed that rails 3.2.4 and 3.2.5 have been released. I don't want to be behind already, so what's the best way to update my app to 3.2.5?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Read the release notes.
- Edit your Gemfile and run `bundle update`.
- Update your `.rvmrc` file. *(Optional)*
- Run your tests.
- Repeat as necessary.

One caveat is that if you do not explicitly specify gem versions in your Gemfile you may update a gem and introduce breaking changes; I have been bitten by this because of my Gemfile laziness.

Comment: @pguardiario No, particularly for a minor point release. You'd need to do a `bundle install` to get the updated rails. But seriously, read the release notes (which you should be doing anyway)--if there's anything out-of-the-ordinary, info will be in the release notes.

Comment: That's perfect. I did have to do bundle update instead of install for some reason but I'm on 3.2.5 now with no issues. Thanks!

Comment: @pguardiario Oops, that's what I meant; my bad--glad you worked it out. I'll update the answer with your comment.