# How to upgrade rails 4.2.4 to 4.2.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails current version is 4.2.4 and I saw that there's 4.2.6 version already.

I know it's just a minor update and it's okay not to, but I just want to know how. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866825/migrating-minor-rails-versions  - the process is the same

Answer (score -1):

Edit your `Gemfile` with new version of rails which you want e.g.

```
gem 'rails',   '4.2.6'
```

Run this command :

```
bundle update
```